# How to Detect css by iPhone/iPad

Tags: html, css

I want to change the css style according to devices.

I wrote like this

```
 <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Destop.css")"
media="only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) "/>

 <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/iphone.css")"
media="only screen  and (max-device-width: 480px) "/>

 <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ipad.css")"
media="only screen  and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) "/>
```

But it works only destop.
Ipad and Iphone didn't load the style sheet.

Please tell me what is the wrong with mu code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with media queries. Below details will definitely helps you to acheive this.

iPad in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

iPad in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

iPad in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries

If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics, or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.

Retina iPad in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Retina iPad in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Retina iPad in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries

If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work like a charm in your responsive design!

iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){ /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

iPad 1 & 2 in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

iPad 1 & 2 in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Reference : http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/